# keyboard dead when connecting with x2go for normal users, works with root

Tags: centos6, x2go

We are using x2go to connect to a CentOS 6 virtual machine. It worked fine, but then the computer was moved to a new server, and the IP address was changed. Since then it is still possible to connect with x2go to the virtual machine, but the keyboard is completely dead. The XCFE desktop appears and the mouse works, but when you open a terminal and hit the keys on your keyboard on your client nothing happens. Normal ssh to the same machine and user works fine.

We just discovered that the keyboards work if you login as root instead, so it appears to be a permission problem of some sort. I suspect that the IP address change make a difference somehow.

I have tried deleting everything in ~/x2go* and /tmp/.x2go-username. It didn't help.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to investigate and solve this problem.

Edit: I don't think it is a keyboard mapping problem. The keys are not wrong, they are simply not detected at all. I tried manually setting the keymap with "setxkbmap us" but it doesn't make any difference. It seems that something is stopping keyboard events from reaching the desktop on the server, while leaving other events and messages alone (since mouse and GUI work).

Comment: Can you use a more conventional method of connecting to the VM, like the VM console?

Comment: The server hosting the VM is on another continent and I don't have physical access to it.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything. You have network connectivity to it, right?

Comment: Okay, I understand. Yes, I have network connectivity and I can run ssh to it. Even "ssh -x terminal" works and then I can type in the terminal window that is executed remotely. Only x2go and nxclient refuses to forward keyboard pushes.

The virtual machine is running in vmware, but that's all I know. I don't have much experience with vmware, and I don't know how the console works. If you want me to check something there I need detailed instructions.

Comment: In that case you can use the vSphere client or vSphere web client to access the virtual machine console.

Comment: I found the root cause. Someone had done a partial upgrade on the computer, and left X in an inconsistent state. Doing a full upgrade will fix it. It had nothing to do with vmware. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Okay, I'm new to this. How do I mark this questions as "closed" or "accepted"?

Comment: Nobody said it had anything to do with VMware. The point of all that was for you to be able to access the VM. As for the question, you are welcome to answer it if the answer would be helpful to others, or you can also delete it.